# find the radius such that oxygen is detained in the atmosphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, potential, kinetic-theory

> Find the minimum radius of planet with mean density $\rho$ and
>   temperature $T$ which can detain Oxygen in its atmosphere and $G$ =
>   Universal Gravitational Constant and $M$ is molecular mass of Oxygen
>   gas.

I tried to do it with the kinetic energy of oxygen molecule as $K.E$=$\frac{5mRT}{2M}$
and then equating it with the potential as $\frac{GMm}{R_{planet}}$ but I am getting the wrong answer. Here I assumed that mass of gas is $m$.
$$\frac{5mRT}{2M}=\frac{G\rho \frac{4\pi}{3}R^3m}{R_{planet}}$$
Whats wrong with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the density provided to calculate the planetary mass based on radius. 
I think you need to consider the effect of gravity a single molecule of mass M (from the question) so the energy can equate to the KE calculation. the other m should be the mass of the planet.

Comment: I used the mean density While writing the mass of planet as $rho$=$\frac{Mass of planet}{Volume of planet}$ and why would need to consider effect of gravity on single particle because even if we consider the mass m it would get cancelled from both sides.??

Comment: try KE$=3kT/2$ for one molecule of mass M

Comment: yes that would give the answer. buy why to consider only translational degrees of freedom?

Comment: The concept you want to understand is that only translation of the whole molecule can act against gravity.